# Creating a table more like a smart an instead of a normal list

Tags: tables, diagrams

That is what I have got so far, but it should look more like the picture above, but I am not sure how to code it. I have tried the forest package, but I am not really happy with the output, especially because I would rather have an output like a diagram and not like a tree. I am more than thankful for any tips! [image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\minipagetrue}{\@minipagetrue}

\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,after=\vskip-\baselineskip,label={\textbullet},leftmargin=*,before=\minipagetrue,}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lP{6cm}@{}} 

\textbf{Tests} & \\[5pt]
      1-SP-Tests 2.1 &
        \begin{itemize}
          \item \textbf{Parametrisch}
          \begin{itemize}
            \item Erwartungswerttest, 2.1.1
            \item Anteilswerttest, 2.1.3
          \end{itemize}
            \item \textbf{Nichtparametrisch} (verteilungsfrei)
          \begin{itemize}
            \item Mediantest, 2.1.2
            \item Test auf komplette Verteilung, 2.1.4
          \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}\\
      2-SP-Tests 2.2  & 
        \begin{itemize}
          \item Unverbunden 2.2.1
          \begin{itemize}
            \item \textbf{Parametrisch}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Vergleich von Erwartungswerten, 2.2.1.1
                \item Vergleich von Anteilswerten, 2.2.1.3
                \item Vergleich von Varianzen, 2.2.1.4
            \end{itemize}
          \begin{itemize}
            \item \textbf{Nichtparametrisch} (verteilungsfrei)
            \begin{itemize}
            \item Vergleich von Erwartungswerten, 2.2.1.2
            \item Vergeich zweier Verteilungen, 2.2.1.5
            \end{itemize}
          \end{itemize}
          \end{itemize}
          \item Verbunden 2.2.2
          \begin{itemize}
            \item \textbf{Parametrisch}
            \begin{itemize}
            \item Vergleich von Erwartungswerten, 2.2.2.1
            \item Korrelationstest, 2.2.2.4
            \end{itemize}
          \item \textbf{Nichtparametrisch} (verteilungsfrei)
          \begin{itemize}
            \item Vergleich von Erwartungswerten, 2.2.2.2
            \item Vergleich von Anteilswerten, 2.2.2.3
            \item Rangkorrelationstest, 2.2.2.5
            \item Test auf Unabhängigkeit, 2.2.2.6
          \end{itemize}
          \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}\\

    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this diagram goes off page margin, do some appropriate scaling.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray] (0,2)--(0,-8) (7,2)--(7,-8) (14,2)--(14,-8);
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={text width=6.5cm,font=\sffamily,inner xsep=-10pt}]
\path (0,0) node[below right] {%
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Parametrisch}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Erwartungswerttest, 2.1.1
        \item Anteilswerttest, 2.1.3
    \end{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Nichtparametrisch} (verteilungsfrei)
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Mediantest, 2.1.2
        \item Test auf komplette Verteilung, 2.1.4
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}};
\path (7,0) node[below right] {%
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Parametrisch}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Vergleich von Erwartungswerten, 2.2.1.1
        \item Vergleich von Anteilswerten, 2.2.1.3
        \item Vergleich von Varianzen, 2.2.1.4
    \end{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Nichtparametrisch} (verteilungsfrei)
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Vergleich von Erwartungswerten, 2.2.1.2
        \item Vergeich zweier Verteilungen, 2.2.1.5
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}};
\path (14,0) node[below right] {%
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Parametrisch}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Vergleich von Erwartungswerten, 2.2.2.1
        \item Korrelationstest, 2.2.2.4
    \end{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Nichtparametrisch} (verteilungsfrei)
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Vergleich von Erwartungswerten, 2.2.2.2
        \item Vergleich von Anteilswerten, 2.2.2.3
        \item Rangkorrelationstest, 2.2.2.5
        \item Test auf Unabhängigkeit, 2.2.2.6
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={draw,minimum height=1.5cm,text centered,font=\Large\sffamily}]
\path (7,2) node[above right,text width=13cm] {2-SP-Tests\\2.2};
\path (7,0) node[above right,text width=6cm] {Unverbunden\\2.2.1};
\path (14,0) node[above right,text width=6cm] {Verbunden\\2.2.2};
\path (0,2) node[above right,text width=6cm] {1-SP-Tests\\2.1};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]